# How to stop programs stealing focus when initializing a build in XCode?

Tags: macos, applications, xcode

I'm currently using XCode in conjunction with Unity. When I initiate a build in Unity, it automatically runs XCode. XCode will then steal focus from whatever app I happen to be in. Is there a way of disabling apps stealing focus in OSX?

Comment: When you initiate a build in Unity, does a window or tab also automatically open in Xcode, or is it silent (just the app activates or becomes the focused app)?

Answer (score 6):

You can add this to the Info.plist of Xcode to make it launch in the background:

```
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<string>True</string>
```

(You might need to get write privileges on the Info.plist if you downloaded Xcode from the Mac App Store)

Source and details about what it can break: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20085680-263/keep-applications-from-stealing-focus-when-opening-in-os-x/